# Add PipeSecurity option to NamedPipeServerStream constructor in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, named-pipes, namedpipeserverstream

I am trying to **establish a full duplex bidirectional communication** between **namedpipestream client and server,** in **.net core 3.1**, for that I tried to use a .netframework library

But there is an exception in the server when the client is not available, found out that this is the issue with the constructor not having `PipeSecurity` option as in .net framework.

The issue with this constructor

```
var _pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(
    pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, 
    PipeOptions.Asynchronous | PipeOptions.WriteThrough, 0, 0, pipeSecurity
);
```

So I modified the constructor like

```
var _pipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(
    pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte,
    PipeOptions.Asynchronous | PipeOptions.WriteThrough, 0, 0
);
```

But this is giving exception when the server has no client connected to it.

thanks in advance

Comment: @MathewHD Thankyou for editing and giving support.. :)

Comment: No problem sadly I never used `NamedPipeServerStream` so I can't really help you with that.